# Add custom command to context menu on right click

Tags: regedit

I want to make an custom context menu, just like the "Git GUI Here" and "Git BASH Here" beneath. How can I do that?? I would like to call it "Build here". Ik can't find anything about how to do it, so how can I do it?

[image: Something similar to the Git GUI here eand Git bash here]

I don't even know what tags I should use, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/). I will remove the unnecessary tags :)